# Php count elements inside loop not outside

Tags: php, loops, count

I know how to count elements inside a loop, but tried and can´t find a solution. Actually, I can count the elements in loop in this way:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($Contents as $item) 
{
    $i++;
}

echo $i;
```

But in my case, I have large function and I can do this, but need more time for count elements inside. I can´t put the string for showing number elements inside loop outside of the function. I must show inside loop all number of elements and show as this. Here's an example:

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($Contents as $item)
    {       
        print "Number Elements it´s : $i";
        print "Element ".$i."<br>";
        $i++;
    }
```

The problem here is that the phrase "number elements it´s" always repeats, because inside loop, and all time `$i` show me `0,1,2,3,4,5` ...... and all time the same as number of elements inside loop.

My idea and question is if it´s possible inside loop to show the number of elements and after this show the elements as this structure when executing the script:

```
Númber elements it´s : 12

Element 1
Element 2
Element 3
.
.
.
.......
```

This it´s my question. I hope you understand it all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)?

Comment: I need inside loop some total number elements but inside loop no outside

Comment: Grammar and code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, youu will need to use the [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function for that. If you insist on having it inside the loop, simply do it like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($Contents as $item)
{
    if($i == 0) {
        print "Number of Elements is : " . count($Contents) . "<br><br>";
    }
    print "Element ".$i."<br>";
    $i++;
 }
```